# Community for questions about Algorithm puzzles Like LeetCode, HackerRank, CodeSignal

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there any Stack Exchange community that is available to discuss programming puzzles? Most of the sites have built-in discussion forums (I know LeetCode has one), but I was wondering if there is some outside community that can be used to discuss solutions for these algorithmic problems; suggestions complexity analysis, etc.

Comment: Yeah, like Jeff said, Code Golf would probably be the place to go... just make sure it's really an answerable question!  "To discuss" *can* be kind of open-ended, depending on exactly what you intended by that wording... which doesn't work well on a Q&A site.  Make sure that the question you're asking is seeking a concrete answer about the puzzle and not just discussion.  Otherwise, it would probably be better to take it to [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Answer (score 7):

To quote from [Code Golf's On-Topic page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Non-challenge questions that are related to solving programming puzzles or a particular type of challenge are also on topic. However, if you have a general programming question, it should be asked on Stack Overflow or a different Stack Exchange site.

That makes it seem like it's the right place. If you're not sure, you could always ask in [Code Golf Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/).